# KeyError: 'lattitude'

Tags: python-3.x, api

I'm currently trying to use an API to get the data in Buffalo and return it in from a JSON URL and them place it in the format of: longitude, Latitude, and Viodesc.

However, I believe I am reaching difficulties when iterating due to some values not having latitude and longitude thus giving me a `KeyError` of `'latitude'`.

I'm not sure if this is the fault in my code as well as how to go about changing it

```
import json
from urllib import request

def get_ticket_data(string):
    answer = []
    urlData = string
    webURL = request.urlopen(urlData)
    data = webURL.read()
    ans = json.loads(data.decode())
    for x in ans:
        arr = []
        arr.append(x["lattitude"])
        arr.append(x["longtitude"])
        arr.append(x["viodesc"])
    return answer.append(ans)
```

Comment: Can you double check that you don't have typos in the keys you're looking up? I just edited the question to remove something I'm *pretty* sure was an artifact of copying your code to Stack Overflow, but I'm not sure if the extra 't' characters you have in the remaining code are errors you have in the code you're running, or if they're also new. Your lookups for `'lattitude'` and `'longtitude'` should probably be for `'latitude'` and `'longitude'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the Exception '[KeyError](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError)' which is raised when the particular key is not found. Handle the exception so that even if the key is missing you can move on to the next record without stopping the code.

Code Snippet:

```
import json
from urllib import request

def get_ticket_data(string):
    answer = []
    urlData = string
    webURL = request.urlopen(urlData)
    data = webURL.read()
    ans = json.loads(data.decode())
    for x in ans:
        try:
            arr = []
            arr.append(x["lattit**strong text**ude"])
            arr.append(x["longtitude"])
            arr.append(x["viodesc"])
        except KeyError:
            continue
    return answer.append(ans)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another different attempt would be to check before appending:

```
import json
from urllib import request

def get_ticket_data(string):
    answer = []
    urlData = string
    webURL = request.urlopen(urlData)
    data = webURL.read()
    ans = json.loads(data.decode())
    for x in ans:
        arr = []
        arr.append(x["lattit**strong text**ude"]) if x["lattit**strong text**ude""] else pass
        arr.append(x["longtitude"]) if x["longitude"] else pass
        arr.append(x["viodesc"]) if x["viodesc"] else pass
    return answer.append(ans)
```

Using the inline-if will let you append if the value exists other wise it would not append.

It will all depend on how you will treat the information latter. Another approach would be to fill it with "" in case there is no latitude. For this approach you could do:

```
import json
from urllib import request

def get_ticket_data(string):
    answer = []
    urlData = string
    webURL = request.urlopen(urlData)
    data = webURL.read()
    ans = json.loads(data.decode())
    for x in ans:
        arr = []
        arr.append(x["lattit**strong text**ude"]) if x["lattit**strong text**ude""] else ""
        arr.append(x["longtitude"]) if x["longitude"] else ""
        arr.append(x["viodesc"]) if x["viodesc"] else ""
    return answer.append(ans)
```